# Mysql и php обработчик , проблема с проверкой даты

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Проблема заключается в том,что когда я выбираю дату и время для резерва,файл обработчик не выполняет свою функцию при нахождении схожих дат

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
$user_id = $_POST["user_id"];
$name    = $_POST["name"];
$time    = (int) $_POST["time"];
$date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['datepicker']);
$newdate = strtotime($date);


$newNdate = date('Y-m-d', $newdate);
$room = $_POST["room"];
$currentTime = (int)date('H');

$CheckQuery = "SELECT * FROM room_reserv WHERE room=1 ";
$CheckQueryResult = mysqli_query($connection, $CheckQuery);

 while($CheckQueryRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($CheckQueryResult)
){
      if($CheckQueryRow['rdate'] == $newNdate){

            if($time == $CheckQueryRow['rtime'])
            {
                $_SESSION["message"] = "This date has been reserved already!";                      

            }else{
                 $query  = "INSERT INTO room_reserv (user_id , name , rtime , rdate, room) VALUES ('{$user_id}' , '{$name}' ,'{$time}' , '{$newNdate}', '{$room}') ";
              $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
              redirect_to("discussion.php");

            }


      }else{

              $query  = "INSERT INTO room_reserv (user_id , name , rtime , rdate, room) VALUES ('{$user_id}' , '{$name}' ,'{$time}' , '{$newNdate}', '{$room}') ";
              $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
              redirect_to("discussion.php");

    }


}

}


?>
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чём ошибка

Comment: Выведите значения $CheckQueryRow['rdate'] и $newNdate, что в них? Не может так быть, что изначально даты в разных часовых поясах и при форматировании к Y-m-d, одна дата оказывается в одном дне, а другая в другом? В любом случае выведите значения при помощи echo. У нас нет ваших данных и трудно воспроизвести ситуацию, нужны дополнительные сведения.

Comment: В  $CheckQueryRow['rdate']  , даты которые были занесены ранее при бронировании с календаря, а в  $newNdate - даты которые заносятся в текущий момент с календаря... И я пытаюсь сделать проверку нет ли совпадения по датам,если есть то проверить совпадение по времени

Comment: Выведи на эран значения в цикле для визуализации `echo $CheckQueryRow['rdate'] . ' ' . $newNdate;` и покажи результат